# It's possible FULLTEXT index MYSQL view columns

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I want to search in multiple table, then i try to make a view with FULLTEXT index.

every body can help?

Response will be grate with an example ;)

Comment: Questions are great with an example too, e.g. your table definitions and expected result. In general though, the answer is no: you can neither create an index on a view, nor a fulltext index that spans several tables. If you show us what you need (with an example) or an example for what you currently use (e.g. 2 separate queries, a complicated view, a slow query, ...), you may get alternative solutions.

Comment: sorry if question wasn't clear. i found a way to search in my view with FULLTEXT option.